# Pretty url by removing get parameter not working

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I want to remove the get parameter from the url. For example
Normal url 
`[https://apkleet.com/apk.php/?app=some_app][1]`
What I wanted 
`https://apkleet.com/apk/some_app`

What I tried 
I am successful in removing .php extention from the url from this htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But I am unsuccessful in removing the get parameter from the url here is the code which I tried so far

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^apk/(\d+)*$ ./apk.php?app=$1
```

And here is my full htaccess code - 
Options +FollowSymLinks

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.apkleet\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.m\.apkleet\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/m\.apkleet\.com\/$1" [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^apk/(\d+)*$ ./apk.php?app=$1
```

I tried each and every answer related to my question in stackoverflow.com but non off them seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i got and its working on my system:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^apk/(.+)$ apk.php?app=$1 [L]
```

So on the url bar you put:
https://apkleet.com/apk/some_app

it loads:
https://apkleet.com/apk.php?app=some_app

--

Provided that `apk.php` file is on the root